# SonataMediaBundle Custom Provider

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I'm trying to create two custom providers, one for PDF and another one for ZIP files.

This is my code.

**services.yml**

```
parameters:
    application_sonata_media.zip_class: Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\ZipProvider

services:            
    sonata.media.provider.zip:
        class: %application_sonata_media.zip_class%
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.media.provider }
        arguments:
            - sonata.media.provider.zip
            - @sonata.media.filesystem.local
            - @sonata.media.cdn.server
            - @sonata.media.generator.default
            - @sonata.media.thumbnail.format
            - ['zip']
            - ['application/zip']
```

**sonata_media.yml**

```
sonata_media:
    contexts:
        eag_zip:
            download:
                strategy: sonata.media.security.public_strategy
                mode: http
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.zip
            formats: 
                reference: { quality: 100 }
```

**ZipProvider.php**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider;

use Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\BaseProvider;
use Gaufrette\Filesystem;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\CoreBundle\Model\Metadata;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\CDN\CDNInterface;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Generator\GeneratorInterface;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Metadata\MetadataBuilderInterface;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Model\MediaInterface;
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Thumbnail\ThumbnailInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotNull;

/**
 * Description of ZipProvider
 *
 * @author Juanjo García <juanjogarcia@editartgroup.com>
 */
class ZipProvider extends BaseProvider {
    protected $allowedExtensions;

    protected $allowedMimeTypes;

    protected $metadata;

    /**
     * @param string                                                $name
     * @param \Gaufrette\Filesystem                                 $filesystem
     * @param \Sonata\MediaBundle\CDN\CDNInterface                  $cdn
     * @param \Sonata\MediaBundle\Generator\GeneratorInterface      $pathGenerator
     * @param \Sonata\MediaBundle\Thumbnail\ThumbnailInterface      $thumbnail
     * @param array                                                 $allowedExtensions
     * @param array                                                 $allowedMimeTypes
     * @param \Sonata\MediaBundle\Metadata\MetadataBuilderInterface $metadata
     */
    public function __construct($name, Filesystem $filesystem, CDNInterface $cdn, GeneratorInterface $pathGenerator, ThumbnailInterface $thumbnail, array $allowedExtensions = array(), array $allowedMimeTypes = array(), MetadataBuilderInterface $metadata = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $filesystem, $cdn, $pathGenerator, $thumbnail);

        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
        $this->allowedMimeTypes  = $allowedMimeTypes;
        $this->metadata = $metadata;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getProviderMetadata()
    {
        return new Metadata($this->getName(), $this->getName().'.description', false, 'SonataMediaBundle', array('class' => 'fa fa-file-text-o'));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getReferenceImage(MediaInterface $media)
    {
        return sprintf('%s/%s',
            $this->generatePath($media),
            $media->getProviderReference()
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getReferenceFile(MediaInterface $media)
    {
        return $this->getFilesystem()->get($this->getReferenceImage($media), true);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildEditForm(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('name');
        $formMapper->add('enabled', null, array('required' => false));
        $formMapper->add('authorName');
        $formMapper->add('cdnIsFlushable');
        $formMapper->add('description');
        $formMapper->add('copyright');
        $formMapper->add('binaryContent', 'file', array('required' => false));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildCreateForm(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('binaryContent', 'file', array(
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(),
                new NotNull(),
            ),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildMediaType(FormBuilder $formBuilder)
    {
        $formBuilder->add('binaryContent', 'file');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function postPersist(MediaInterface $media)
    {
        if ($media->getBinaryContent() === null) {
            return;
        }

        $this->setFileContents($media);

        $this->generateThumbnails($media);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function postUpdate(MediaInterface $media)
    {
        if (!$media->getBinaryContent() instanceof \SplFileInfo) {
            return;
        }

        // Delete the current file from the FS
        $oldMedia = clone $media;
        $oldMedia->setProviderReference($media->getPreviousProviderReference());

        $path = $this->getReferenceImage($oldMedia);

        if ($this->getFilesystem()->has($path)) {
            $this->getFilesystem()->delete($path);
        }

        $this->fixBinaryContent($media);

        $this->setFileContents($media);

        $this->generateThumbnails($media);
    }

    /**
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     *
     * @param \Sonata\MediaBundle\Model\MediaInterface $media
     *
     * @return
     */
    protected function fixBinaryContent(MediaInterface $media)
    {
        if ($media->getBinaryContent() === null) {
            return;
        }

        // if the binary content is a filename => convert to a valid File
        if (!$media->getBinaryContent() instanceof File) {
            if (!is_file($media->getBinaryContent())) {
                throw new \RuntimeException('The file does not exist : '.$media->getBinaryContent());
            }

            $binaryContent = new File($media->getBinaryContent());

            $media->setBinaryContent($binaryContent);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     *
     * @param \Sonata\MediaBundle\Model\MediaInterface $media
     */
    protected function fixFilename(MediaInterface $media)
    {
        if ($media->getBinaryContent() instanceof UploadedFile) {
            $media->setName($media->getName() ?: $media->getBinaryContent()->getClientOriginalName());
            $media->setMetadataValue('filename', $media->getBinaryContent()->getClientOriginalName());
        } elseif ($media->getBinaryContent() instanceof File) {
            $media->setName($media->getName() ?: $media->getBinaryContent()->getBasename());
            $media->setMetadataValue('filename', $media->getBinaryContent()->getBasename());
        }

        // this is the original name
        if (!$media->getName()) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Please define a valid media\'s name');
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function doTransform(MediaInterface $media)
    {
        $this->fixBinaryContent($media);
        $this->fixFilename($media);

        // this is the name used to store the file
        if (!$media->getProviderReference()) {
            $media->setProviderReference($this->generateReferenceName($media));
        }

        if ($media->getBinaryContent()) {
            $media->setContentType($media->getBinaryContent()->getMimeType());
            $media->setSize($media->getBinaryContent()->getSize());
        }

        $media->setProviderStatus(MediaInterface::STATUS_OK);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function updateMetadata(MediaInterface $media, $force = true)
    {
        // this is now optimized at all!!!
        $path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'sonata_update_metadata');
        $fileObject = new \SplFileObject($path, 'w');
        $fileObject->fwrite($this->getReferenceFile($media)->getContent());

        $media->setSize($fileObject->getSize());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function generatePublicUrl(MediaInterface $media, $format)
    {
        if ($format == 'reference') {
            $path = $this->getReferenceImage($media);
        } else {
            // @todo: fix the asset path
            $path = sprintf('sonatamedia/files/%s/file.png', $format);
        }

        return $this->getCdn()->getPath($path, $media->getCdnIsFlushable());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getHelperProperties(MediaInterface $media, $format, $options = array())
    {
        return array_merge(array(
            'title'       => $media->getName(),
            'thumbnail'   => $this->getReferenceImage($media),
            'file'        => $this->getReferenceImage($media),
        ), $options);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function generatePrivateUrl(MediaInterface $media, $format)
    {
        if ($format == 'reference') {
            return $this->getReferenceImage($media);
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Set the file contents for an image.
     *
     * @param \Sonata\MediaBundle\Model\MediaInterface $media
     * @param string                                   $contents path to contents, defaults to MediaInterface BinaryContent
     */
    protected function setFileContents(MediaInterface $media, $contents = null)
    {
        $file = $this->getFilesystem()->get(sprintf('%s/%s', $this->generatePath($media), $media->getProviderReference()), true);

        if (!$contents) {
            $contents = $media->getBinaryContent()->getRealPath();
        }

        $metadata = $this->metadata ? $this->metadata->get($media, $file->getName()) : array();
        $file->setContent(file_get_contents($contents), $metadata);
    }

    /**
     * @param \Sonata\MediaBundle\Model\MediaInterface $media
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function generateReferenceName(MediaInterface $media)
    {
        return sha1($media->getName().rand(11111, 99999)).'.'.$media->getBinaryContent()->guessExtension();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getDownloadResponse(MediaInterface $media, $format, $mode, array $headers = array())
    {
        // build the default headers
        $headers = array_merge(array(
            'Content-Type'          => $media->getContentType(),
            'Content-Disposition'   => sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', $media->getMetadataValue('filename')),
        ), $headers);

        if (!in_array($mode, array('http', 'X-Sendfile', 'X-Accel-Redirect'))) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Invalid mode provided');
        }

        if ($mode == 'http') {
            if ($format == 'reference') {
                $file = $this->getReferenceFile($media);
            } else {
                $file = $this->getFilesystem()->get($this->generatePrivateUrl($media, $format));
            }

            return new StreamedResponse(function () use ($file) {
                echo $file->getContent();
            }, 200, $headers);
        }

        if (!$this->getFilesystem()->getAdapter() instanceof \Sonata\MediaBundle\Filesystem\Local) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Cannot use X-Sendfile or X-Accel-Redirect with non \Sonata\MediaBundle\Filesystem\Local');
        }

        $filename = sprintf('%s/%s',
            $this->getFilesystem()->getAdapter()->getDirectory(),
            $this->generatePrivateUrl($media, $format)
        );

        return new BinaryFileResponse($filename, 200, $headers);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validate(ErrorElement $errorElement, MediaInterface $media)
    {
        if (!$media->getBinaryContent() instanceof \SplFileInfo) {
            return;
        }

        if ($media->getBinaryContent() instanceof UploadedFile) {
            $fileName = $media->getBinaryContent()->getClientOriginalName();
        } elseif ($media->getBinaryContent() instanceof File) {
            $fileName = $media->getBinaryContent()->getFilename();
        } else {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Invalid binary content type: %s', get_class($media->getBinaryContent())));
        }

        if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), $this->allowedExtensions)) {
            $errorElement
                ->with('binaryContent')
                    ->addViolation('Invalid extensions')
                ->end();
        }

        if (!in_array($media->getBinaryContent()->getMimeType(), $this->allowedMimeTypes)) {
            $errorElement
                ->with('binaryContent')
                    ->addViolation('Invalid mime type : '.$media->getBinaryContent()->getMimeType())
                ->end();
        }
    }
}
```

When I push create and edit button, the file pass the validation, save in DDBB and file in server, but in URL **/admin/sonata/media/media/233/edit?provider=sonata.media.provider.zip&context=eag_zip** I get this Error message:

> Unable to find template "" in SonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:edit.html.twig at line 48.

Trying to go to **/admin/sonata/media/media/list?provider=sonata.media.provider.zip&context=eag_zip** or **/admin/sonata/media/media/list?context=eag_zip**

> Unable to find template "" in SonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:inner_row_media.html.twig at line 19.

I don't know to solve it.

any help would be welcome

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved [here](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/issues/955#issuecomment-192458568)

```
services:            
    sonata.media.provider.zip:
        class: %application_sonata_media.zip_class%
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.media.provider }
        arguments:
            - sonata.media.provider.zip
            - @sonata.media.filesystem.local
            - @sonata.media.cdn.server
            - @sonata.media.generator.default
            - @sonata.media.thumbnail.format
            - ['zip']
            - ['application/zip']
        calls:
          - [ setTemplates, [{helper_view:SonataMediaBundle:Provider:view_image.html.twig,helper_thumbnail:SonataMediaBundle:Provider:thumbnail.html.twig}]]
```